# Why the staggered Euler (Euler-Backward) method is not runge-kutta method?

Tags: runge-kutta-methods, eulers-method

Why the staggered Euler (Euler-Backward) method is not runge-kutta method?

The method is given by
$$x_{n+1}=x_n+hg(p_{n+1})$$
$$p_{n+1}=p_n+hg(x_n)$$

I am not very familiar with the conditions of the Runge-kutta method, can someone help me with this? thank you.

Comment: Why should it be considered by that name?  The Wikipedia article on [Runge-Kutta methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods) gives a nice outline of the original fourth-order explicit method and its generalizations to higher-order, adaptive, and mixed implicit-explicit methods (none of which would bring the comparatively primitive Euler backward method under this umbrella).

Comment: You may be interested in the Wikipedia article [LIst of Runge-Kutta methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods), which does mention backward Euler (under implicit methods).  I think the intent (if one exists for a collectively authored post) is to present this first-order method "for comparison".

Answer (score 1):

If the system is something like a separable Hamiltonian system $(\dot x,\dot p)=(f(p),g(x))$, then a simple Runge-Kutta method would apply to both components in the same way, according to the Butcher tableau of the method. This is obviously not the case with the named correction, as the functions are evaluated at different time points.

To be more specific, reordered as
$$p_{n+1}=p_n+hg(x_n)
\\
x_{n+1}=x_n+hf(p_{n+1})$$
the method is one of the variants of the [symplectic or semi-implicit Euler methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-implicit_Euler_method), which can also be classified under *partitioned* Runge-Kutta methods.

---

On a later second review, if the $p$ are considered intermediate values in the integration of $\dot x=g(x)$, and the second equation were corrected to
$$
p_{n+1}=x_n+hg(x_n)
$$
then the method is indeed Runge-Kutta with Butcher tableau
$$
\begin{array}{c|cc}
0&\\
1&0&1\\
\hline
&0&1
\end{array}
$$
This could also be interpreted as the PECE (predict-evaluate-correct-evaluate) implementation of the implicit Euler method, with the explicit Euler step as predictor.